# Implement modf function with AVX SIMD intrinsics

Tags: c++, sse, simd, avx

I want to write `std::modf` function with SIMD instructions. My processor doesn't provide `__m256d _mm256_trunc_pd`.

I want to write analog of `modf` function for  `__m256d` type.

I have `_mm256_floor_pd`, but unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: [`vroundpd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/roundpd) only requires AVX1 and implements trunc/floor/ceil/nearest.  It's your *compiler* that's not providing `_mm256_trunc_pd`.

Use `__m256d _mm256_round_pd(__m256d s1, int iRoundMode);` manually - Intel's intrinsics guides should document CPP macros for the rounding mode names.

Comment: Did you just make up the `_mm256_trunc_pd` name?  Even [Intel's intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&expand=1879&text=roundpd) doesn't list a trunc intrinsic for `roundpd`.  It would make sense for that to exist, but probably no compilers have that wrapper; you just need to use `_mm256_round_pd(vec, _MM_FROUND_TO_ZERO |_MM_FROUND_NO_EXC)`

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, you just said you wanted rounding with truncation towards zero.  My previous comments show how to do that with one intrinsic for a single instruction (which is fairly efficient on most CPUs, only 2 uops.)  That's why I didn't post it as an answer to your whole question.

Comment: @KK_1999 If you have a working solution, I suggest posting that as an answer (so future readers don't have to scan through the comments)